# Python Requests splits TCP packet

Tags: python, tcp, python-requests

I am trying to script a HTTP POST request with python.

When trying it with curl from bash, everything is working. With python, using either the `requests` or the `urllib3`-library, I am getting an error response from the API. The POST request contains information in headers and as json in the request body.

What I noticed, when I intercept the packets with Wireshark, the curl-request (which is working) is one single packet of length 374 bytes. The python-request (no difference between `requests` and `urllib3` here) is splitted into 2 separate packets of 253 and 144 bytes length.

[image]

Wireshark reassembles these without problems and they both seem to contain the complete information in header and POST body. But the API I am trying to connect to answeres with a not very helpful "Error when processing request".

As the 253 bytes can't be the limit of a TCP-packet, what is the reason for that behavior? Is there a way to fix that?

EDIT:

bash:

```
curl 'http://localhost/test.php' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2","key3":"value3"}'
```

python:

```
import requests, json

headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36",
"Content-Type": "application/json"}

data = {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3":"value3"}

r=requests.post("http://localhost/test.php", headers=headers, data=json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Could you add the sample pieces of code you are using that generate these results?

Comment: Sorry, I added my code without sensitive information below!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TCP is a data stream and not a series of messages. The segmentation of the data stream into packets should be of no relevance to the interpretation of the data stream, neither in sender nor recipient. If the recipients actually behaves differently based on the segmentation of the packets the the recipient is broken.

While I've seen such broken systems I've seen more systems which do not like the request for different reasons, like wrong user agent, missing accept header or similar. I would suggest you check this first before concluding that it must be the segmentation of the data stream.

As for why curl and requests behave differently: probably curl first constructs the full request (header and body) and sends it while requests constructs first the header and sends it and then sends the body, i.e. does two write operations which might result in two packets.

Comment: As I have no influence on the server-side API, do you have any proposal how I can achieve the same result in python as in bash?

Comment: @ChristianH: Given that I'm not even sure what the problem is (see my answer) it is hard to make any recommendations. What I usually do is to create the full request myself by hand for testing, send it using a socket directly to the server and then play around with the sending and the request until I find out what the real issue is the server does not like, i.e. a specific header (or missing header) or really the segmentation of the data stream.

Answer (score 2):

Although it should not matter for the issue you are having, there is a way to force the data being sent into one packet for multiple sends, namely using the TCP_CORK option on the socket (platform dependent though).

Create an adapter first:

```
from requests.packages.urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection

class HTTPAdapterWithSocketOptions(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.socket_options = kwargs.pop("socket_options", None)
        super(HTTPAdapterWithSocketOptions, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.socket_options is not None:
            kwargs["socket_options"] = self.socket_options
        super(HTTPAdapterWithSocketOptions, self).init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)
```

Then use it for the requests you want to send out:

```
s = requests.Session()
options = HTTPConnection.default_socket_options + [ (socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_CORK, 1)]
adapter = HTTPAdapterWithSocketOptions(socket_options=options)
s.mount("http://", adapter)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sadly there are indeed very broken systems as @Steffen Ullrich explains (even though they claim to be industry standards) which aren't capable of handling fragmented TCP frames. Since my application/script is rather isolated and self-contained, I used the simpler **workaround** based on @Roeften 's answer which applies TCP_CORK to all connections.

**Warning**: this **workaround** makes sense only in situations when you don't risk breaking any other functionality relying on `requests`.

```
requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection.default_socket_options = [(6,3,1)]
```